# Как провести получаемую информацию через скрипт Python на сервере?

Tags: python, http, backend

Есть сервер, на котором располагается .py скрипт, который обрабатывает xml файл, форматируя его в json по стандартам, необходимым для работы с ним в дальнейшем.

Информация (xml) приходит с 1С. Как правильно реализовать обработку получаемой инфы через скрипт? Есть ли средства отследить процесс, мол:

- Пришёл запрос.
- Провожу его через .py скрипт
- Процесс завершён
- Отдаю его в работу

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, вы вполне можете записать все желаемые вами действия, процессы и их отслеживания в Python-коде любым удобным для вас способом, вас ничто не ограничивает. У вас какие-то трудности возникли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для apache, в конфигурации дописываем

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#....
<Directory "/var/vhosts/www/test">
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

обязательно перезапускаем апач. В debian/ubuntu это

> sudo service apache2 restart

и создаем тестовый скрипт /var/vhosts/www/test/a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n")
print("HELLO\r\n")
```

теперь можно проверить в браузере к примеру http://myhost/test/a.py (если корневой каталог сайта /var/vhosts/www)